# Snail speed for raster extraction looping in R using traditional or Parallelisation method

Tags: r, performance, loops, raster

"Assistance needed from experts in rapidly extracting values from a number of rasters in R"

I'm trying to extract values from rasters for points (longitude and latitude). There are millions of points and thousands of rasters indexed with dates (year-month-day). For each point, values are to be extracted from several rasters. The rasters to be extracted vary across points. A sample of the database and rasters is shown in the image.

[image: database and rasters]

My Operations in R software:
I firstly created a stack in R to store all rasters, then a loop was used for raster extraction using two Methods: (1) tradition loop; (2) loop with Parallelisation

(1) traditional loop

```
library(raster);library(lubridate)
a<-read.csv("cc_data_preparation.csv",header=T)
a1<-a[,6:7]
###################################################################
folder<-paste0("JS_",c(2015330:2015365,2016001:2016366,2017001:2017365,
                   2018001:2018365,2019001:2019365),
           ".tif")
for(i in 1:length(folder)){
  z1<-raster(folder[i])
  z1[is.na(z1)]<-NA;z1[z1==0]<-NA
  plot(z1)
  if(i==1){h<-stack(z1)}else(h<-stack(h,z1))
}
#########################################
g<-a[,57:85]
for(i in 1:nrow(a)){
  for(j in 1:29){
    w<-as.Date(a[i,j+56])#### row 1
    k<-ifelse(yday(w)<=9,paste0("00",yday(w)),
              ifelse(yday(w)>9 & yday(w) <=99,paste0("0",yday(w)),
                     yday(w)))
    k1<-paste0('JS_',format(w,"%Y"),k)
    ##############################################################
    m<- raster::subset(h, grep(k1, names(h), value = T))
    g[i,j]<-extract(m, SpatialPoints(a[i,6:7]),fun="mean")
      }}
```

(2) loop with Parallelisation

```
library(raster);library(lubridate)
library(doParallel)  #Foreach Parallel Adaptor 
library(foreach)     #Provides foreach looping construct
a<-read.csv("cc_data_preparation.csv",header=T)
a1<-a[,6:7]
###################################################################
folder<-paste0("JS_",c(2015330:2015365,2016001:2016366,2017001:2017365,
                   2018001:2018365,2019001:2019365),
           ".tif")
for(i in 1:length(folder)){
  z1<-raster(folder[i])
  z1[is.na(z1)]<-NA;z1[z1==0]<-NA
  plot(z1)
  if(i==1){h<-stack(z1)}else(h<-stack(h,z1))
}
#########################################
g<-a[,57:85]
###################################################*****
#Define how many cores you want to use
UseCores <- detectCores() -1
#Register CoreCluster
cl<- makeCluster(UseCores)
registerDoParallel(cl)  
###################################################*****
foreach(i=1:nrow(a)) %dopar% {
   foreach(j=1:29) %dopar% {
        w<-as.Date(a[i,j+56])#### row 1
    k<-ifelse(yday(w)<=9,paste0("00",yday(w)),
              ifelse(yday(w)>9 & yday(w) <=99,paste0("0",yday(w)),
                     yday(w)))
    k1<-paste0('JS_',format(w,"%Y"),k)
##############################################################
m<- raster::subset(h, grep(k1, names(h), value = T))
g[i,j]<-extract(m, SpatialPoints(a[i,6:7]),fun="mean")
      }}

#end cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

For two methods, the loop in the last step is still running after waiting for several days!!!
Does someone can help me out. I've been searching for solutions for several months. Much appreciated for any guidance.

Comment: whats the size of `a`?

Comment: whats the values of `names(h)`? why are you using `grep` in 'raster::subset'? cant we use exact matches?

Comment: about `doParallel`, I think you are not meant to define one `foreach` inside another...

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `plot(z1)` from first loop, I guess that's slow.

As you did not provide minimal example, I created some example/test data:

```
# creating fake data:
w <- as.Date(sample(1:100), origin = "1900-01-01")
a <- lapply(1:29, function(x) as.character(w + x))

# fake raster stack
r <- raster(ncol = 20, nrow = 20)
r[] <- 1:(20*20)
n <- unique(unlist(a))
k <- sprintf("%03d", yday(n))
n <- paste0('JS_', format(w, "%Y"), k)
h <- lapply(1:length(n), function(i) r + i)
h <- stack(h)
names(h) <- n

# fake a
a <- as.data.frame(a)
x <- sapply(1:56, function(x) rep(1L, nrow(a)))
a <- cbind(x, a)
a[, 6] <- a[, 7] <- 1:nrow(a)
```

Improved second loop:

```
# 2nd loop
nh <- names(h)
sp <- SpatialPoints(a[, 6:7])
g <- sapply(1:29, function(j) {
  w <- as.Date(a[, j + 56])
  k <- sprintf("%03d", yday(w)) # adding leading zeros
  k1 <- paste0('JS_', format(w, "%Y"), k)
  m <- raster::subset(h, k1)
  r <- extract(m, sp)
  r <- diag(r)
  return(r)
})
g
```

Multiple loops replaced with one `sapply`(loop) over columns.
Removed `grep` as I think this is not needed. If your names are different, or contains some extension(`".tif"`?), try to add/adjust that on `paste0` line to create exact matches.
Also, as you are extracting one point from each layer, why did you specify `mean` in `extract`?
Try this first on subset of original data, so you do not have to wait for multiple days... to find out something isn't working as intended.